# Problems with converting JSON data I got from an API into something more usable in Python

Tags: python, json

So I'm trying to make a program converting [this](https://api.evemarketer.com/ec/marketstat/json?typeid=0&typeid=1&typeid=2&typeid=3&typeid=4&typeid=5&typeid=6&typeid=7&typeid=8&typeid=9&typeid=10&typeid=11&typeid=12&typeid=13&typeid=14&typeid=15&typeid=16&typeid=17&typeid=18&typeid=19&typeid=20&typeid=21&typeid=22&typeid=23&typeid=24&typeid=25&typeid=26&typeid=27&typeid=28&typeid=29&typeid=30&typeid=31&typeid=32&typeid=33&typeid=34&typeid=35&typeid=36&typeid=37&typeid=38&typeid=39&typeid=40&typeid=41&typeid=42&typeid=43&typeid=44&typeid=45&typeid=46&typeid=47&typeid=48&typeid=49&typeid=50&typeid=51&typeid=52&typeid=53&typeid=54&typeid=55&typeid=56&typeid=57&typeid=58&typeid=59&typeid=60&typeid=61&typeid=62&typeid=63&typeid=64&typeid=65&typeid=66&typeid=67&typeid=68&typeid=69&typeid=70&typeid=71&typeid=72&typeid=73&typeid=74&typeid=75&typeid=76&typeid=77&typeid=78&typeid=79&typeid=80&typeid=81&typeid=82&typeid=83&typeid=84&typeid=85&typeid=86&typeid=87&typeid=88&typeid=89&typeid=90&typeid=91&typeid=92&typeid=93&typeid=94&typeid=95&typeid=96&typeid=97&typeid=98&typeid=99&typeid=100&typeid=101&typeid=102&typeid=103&typeid=104&typeid=105&typeid=106&typeid=107&typeid=108&typeid=109&typeid=110&typeid=111&typeid=112&typeid=113&typeid=114&typeid=115&typeid=116&typeid=117&typeid=118&typeid=119&typeid=120&typeid=121&typeid=122&typeid=123&typeid=124&typeid=125&typeid=126&typeid=127&typeid=128&typeid=129&typeid=130&typeid=131&typeid=132&typeid=133&typeid=134&typeid=135&typeid=136&typeid=137&typeid=138&typeid=139&typeid=140&typeid=141&typeid=142&typeid=143&typeid=144&typeid=145&typeid=146&typeid=147&typeid=148&typeid=149&typeid=150&typeid=151&typeid=152&typeid=153&typeid=154&typeid=155&typeid=156&typeid=157&typeid=158&typeid=159&typeid=160&typeid=161&typeid=162&typeid=163&typeid=164&typeid=165&typeid=166&typeid=167&typeid=168&typeid=169&typeid=170&typeid=171&typeid=172&typeid=173&typeid=174&typeid=175&typeid=176&typeid=177&typeid=178&typeid=179&typeid=180&typeid=181&typeid=182&typeid=183&typeid=184&typeid=185&typeid=186&typeid=187&typeid=188&typeid=189&typeid=190&typeid=191&typeid=192&typeid=193&typeid=194&typeid=195&typeid=196&typeid=197&typeid=198&typeid=199&) sort of data into something like a dictionary or some sort of small database I can play with. If I just do this:

```
response = requests.get(url_final).json()
print(response)
```

I get a massive, unformated list.

When I do this

```
response = requests.get(url_final).json()
for item in response:
        print(item)
```

The list is split into 200 dictionaries, which only display 'buy' and 'sell' strings when I run through them with another for loop. The only module that I used was 'requests'. I'm really new to programming in general and don't know how to approach this kind of problem.
Would really appreciate some help.

Thank you :)

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello and welcome to stack overflow!

The problem has to do with what 'in' means.

response, as you mentioned, is a list. `for x in list` iterates over every item in the list. However, `item` is a dictionary. When you iterate over a dictionary, you just get keys. Consider this example:

```py
obj = { 'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 3 }

for item in obj:
    print(item)
```

It will print out:

```
a
b
c
```

This is what is happening to  you. To fix it you have a few options. Perhaps the easiest is something like this:

```py
response = requests.get(url).json()
for item in response:
    for key in item:
        print(f'{key} -> {item[key]}')
```

Here, we access the value that the key points to.

Another option would be this:

```py
response = requests.get(url).json()
for item in response:
    for key, val in item.items():
        print(f'{key} -> {val}')
```

Dictionaries have a special `items()` function that returns a list of their items

Comment: I guess it kind of worked :). But is there a way to go a bit deeper into that dictionary, like checking if the volume is 0 for example?

Comment: Edit: It works when I convert it to a string and then use the 'in' operator but I think it would be better to use some kind of data structure for this. :)